# Make yocto skip a recipe instead of stopping

Tags: yocto, openembedded, recipe

I have a recipe that does a check during parsing. What I would like to do is instead of issuing a warning or stopping with an error, I would like to make yocto completely ignore the recipe as if it was never there. It could still error out if some other recipe `RDEPENDS` on it, but otherwise parsing would be successful.

Is this possible to do?

Answer (score 9):

EDIT: I don't see a way to do it.

But you can "hide" specific recipe(s) using the `BBMASK` variable. The value is regexp for masking specific files or paths. You can also mask a whole directory.

We are using that mechanism and the variable is set in configuration file (distro configuration in our case, but it may be in a different configuration file).

You can find more information in the documentation for that variable: https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/latest/mega-manual/mega-manual.html#var-BBMASK

Some examples copied from the linked documentation:

```
BBMASK += "/meta-ti/recipes-misc/ meta-ti/recipes-ti/packagegroup/"
BBMASK += "/meta-oe/recipes-support/"
BBMASK += "/meta-foo/.*/openldap"
BBMASK += "opencv.*\.bbappend"
BBMASK += "lzma"
```

Comment: This is not exactly what I had in mind. What I wanted is a way to dynamically decide whether to hide the recipe while parsing it (upvoted since it is still a useful answer for someone with a similar problem).

Comment: @user18197 Could you move the check from that recipe to some configuration file? Something similar to "dynamic layers" approach might be helpful. meta-freescale layer uses it to add some bbappends, but only in case that the respective layer exists in user's workspace (otherwise parsing error would appear). They are adding recipes to `BBFILES` based on `BBFILE_COLLECTIONS` (selected layers). See https://github.com/Freescale/meta-freescale/blob/bf7fd9cfe0788fe2f819a4ae2cc7db8327fe161a/conf/layer.conf#L28

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can, by raising bb.parse.SkipRecipe exception

```
python() {
  ...
  if ... :
    raise bb.parse.SkipRecipe("Message")
  ...
}
```

I don't find it well documented, but google does return some assuring results for this.

Answer (score 0):

When bitbake launches, it first parses everything it can in order to figure out what does it have and are there any obvious errors. Only after this stage it analyzes what have you asked it to do. So if you have syntax errors there is no other way to avoid it except don't add the layer that contains invalid recipe to bblayers.conf.